# Debug memory leak of php extention so with valgrind

Tags: php, debugging, memory-leaks, valgrind, shared-libraries

There are lots of '?' in the log when debugging memory leak of an php extenstion so with valgrind.It is suggested that the program should avoid calling dlclose on shared objects.
How can I do this? Could it be said that it can only be achieved by modifying the source code of php?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install debugging symbols for your php build ... lots of packaging systems make the debug package available separately to the release package. The package, if available will usually be named using the convention php-debug/php-dbg/php53-dbg/php53-debug.

If it's not available, then you'll need to compile yourself a copy of PHP with debugging enabled, to do this and not disturb your current installation it's usually enough to add --prefix=/my/private/folder to the configure options. To enable debugging add --enable-debug, you'll then need to recompile the php extension ( I assume it's from pecl if it has leaks ) starting with make clean and then /my/private/folder/bin/phpize.

Good Luck :)

Comment: ：I know this will help. However,I wonder if there is a better option.

Comment: The ? will be replaced with useful information when debug symbols are present. Then you will know what is going on, in which file, function and line and using gdb and breakpoints you'll be sure to find the error.
The other thing you might try is asking the extension author to check against your PHP version if the project is still maintained ...